# Reading whole directory with Spark except one file

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I have the following directory containing these CSV files:

```
/data/one.csv
/data/two.csv
/data/three.csv
/data/four.csv
```

If I want to read everything, I can simply do:

```
/data/*.csv
```

but I can not seem to read everything, except `four.csv`.

This:

```
/data/*[^four]*.csv
```

seemed to work but I think that if the list of files would be bigger, than this way of reading would probably be wrong (because of double wildcards).

Is there a good way to do this? I also am aware that:

```
/data/{one,two,three,^four}.csv
```

would solve this specific case, but I need the except method for future needs.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that this method will work, but you can try. You can use Bash/Python or whatever script to scan all the csv files in the folder, but not with the names `four.csv`.
The input for spark will be (assuming you have files:  one.csv, two.csv, three.csv, four.csv, five.csv ,...up to n.csv  files)
`PathToFiles=[/data/one.csv, /data/two.csv, /data/three.csv, /data/five.csv, ..., /data/n.csv]`

Then you can use (the code is in python)
`filesRDD = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(",".join(PathToFiles))`

I have wrote similar code in java, in my impression, it works and you can try.